# emacsで縦に分割した画面を左右で入れ替えたい

Tags: emacs

emacsで、`C-x 3`して、画面を左右に２分割したあとに、左右のwindowを入れ替えるにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

画面が2分割されている時に、それらの位置を入れ替える関数です。

```
;; from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransposeWindows
(defun swap-window-positions ()         ; Stephen Gildea
  "*Swap the positions of this window and the next one."
  (interactive)
  (let ((other-window (next-window (selected-window) 'no-minibuf)))
    (let ((other-window-buffer (window-buffer other-window))
          (other-window-hscroll (window-hscroll other-window))
          (other-window-point (window-point other-window))
          (other-window-start (window-start other-window)))
      (set-window-buffer other-window (current-buffer))
      (set-window-hscroll other-window (window-hscroll (selected-window)))
      (set-window-point other-window (point))
      (set-window-start other-window (window-start (selected-window)))
      (set-window-buffer (selected-window) other-window-buffer)
      (set-window-hscroll (selected-window) other-window-hscroll)
      (set-window-point (selected-window) other-window-point)
      (set-window-start (selected-window) other-window-start))
    (select-window other-window)))
```